# not able to login by ftp

Tags: configuration, vsftpd, kubuntu, access-control

I've installed `vsftp` and set the home directory of user `ftp` with `sudo usermod -d /var/www/ ftp` , I've also set the password with `sudo passwd ftp` and restarted the server but I can not login with user ftp when I try with `ftp 127.0.0.1`, why not? What may be wrong here?
This is on a Kubuntu 13.04 box.

```
$ ftp 127.0.0.1
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (127.0.0.1:reg): ftp
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
ftp>
```

Answer (score 1):

vsftp like a lot of ftp servers does its own private authorization based on files in a vsftp-specific directory. See the [vsftpd.conf](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html) manpage for details, the user config stuff is down at the end there.